# Populate Combo Box with distinct values and apply filter?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, combobox, kendo-combobox

here is my code to controller

```
    var products = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            batch: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "/api/Companies/GetAllCompanies",
                }
            }
        })
```

here is my controller code

```
     [HttpGet]
    public List<DefCurrencyDTO> GetAllCompanies()
    {

        List<DefCurrencyDTO> test = DefCurrency.AllCurrency;

        return test;
    }
```

html code:

```
  <input id="products" style="width: 300px" data-bind="value: CurrentCurrencyCode "/>
```

and on click clear how to make combobox value equal to null code:

```
  document.getElementById('products').value = null;
```

things i want to do

1-filter distinct values?

Comment: I see no mention of a combobox anywhere... what is the json response from the controller?

Comment: Also your input element has no type..

Comment: see the above i have populated combobox but problem is filteration and editing and onclick auto select the value against id of grid view

Comment: now the problem is filtering distinct values

Answer (score 0):

Replace "`Text`" with the "`text`".

I think there is a Typo in the code:

```
$("#products").kendoDropDownList({     
    dataTextField: "Text",   <---------------- Here you wrote "Text" instead of "text"
    dataValueField: "value",
    filterable: true,
    filter: "contains",
    dataSource: products
});
```

Comment: see the above i have populated combobox but problem is filteration and editing and onclick auto select the value against id of grid view

Comment: problem is filteration and clear click value becom null see above code for null but not works